# I can't access a variable defined inside an IIFE

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
(function() {
    var libby = {};

    libby.greet = function() {
        console.log('heello');
    }
    return libby;
})();
```

I am learning to create a JavaScript library. I include above file in my html and load the page, the library loads, but when I type `libby` in the console, it throws the error "libby is not defined".

Answer (score 2):

You've to get the returned value in a variable.

```
var libby = (function () {

    var libby = {};

    libby.greet = function () {
        console.log('heello');
    };
    return libby;
}());
```

The value returned from the IIFE is assigned to the global variable `libby`. Note that the inner `libby` variable is *private* and is not accessible outside of the IIFE.

---

The local variable can also be added on global `window` object.

```
(function () {

    var libby = {};

    libby.greet = function () {
        console.log('heello');
    };

    window.libby = libby; // Make it global
}());
```

Comment: Thats. correct!!
attaching it to window object works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point of your IIFE closure. 
Your library variables now won't collide with variables from other libs.
If you want to use your library you need a variable outside the IIFE that gives global scope access to library functions.

```
var somePrivateName = (function() {

    var libby= {};

    libby.greet = function() 
       {        
        console.log('heello');  
      }     return libby;   
})();
```

Now you can use `somePrivateName` to access the library features.

```
 somePrivateName.greet();
```